# I cannot make a GET call with date as a query

Tags: java, spring-boot

So I have this Flight entity:

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "flights")
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Flight{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long flightId;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="departure_from", referencedColumnName="location")
    private Airport departureFrom;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="arrival_to", referencedColumnName="location")
    private Airport arrivalTo;
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", shape = Shape.STRING)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "departure_date", columnDefinition = "DATETIME")
    private Date departureDate;
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", shape = Shape.STRING)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "return_date", columnDefinition = "DATETIME")
    private Date returnDate;
    private Long flightPrice;
}
```

With which I can successfully use to create instances with a POST call.
However, when I try to make a GET call with the queries of departureFrom, arrivalTo, departureDate and returnDate, I get the error:

> Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type
> 'java.util.Date'.

My code for this is:

```
    @GetMapping("/flights/search/id")
    public ResponseEntity<?> searchFlightsById(@RequestParam("departure_from") Airport departureFrom, @RequestParam("arrival_at") Airport arrivalAt, @RequestParam("departure_date") @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") Date departureDate, @RequestParam("return_date") @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") Optional<Date> returnDate){
        return ResponseEntity.ok(flightService.fetchFlights(departureFrom, arrivalAt, departureDate, returnDate));
    }
```

When I make the call without the Date queries, I get the date looking like YYYY:MM:dd HH:mm:ss. This is also how it looks like in mySQL as well. So the date format seems to be correct.

I'm a novice to SpringBoot and almost a beginner in Java, so any tips are appreciated on how to solve this issue!

Comment: What are you passing exactly? Provide data and steps for reproduction. Show the complete error from the log, not just the message.

Answer (score 0):

try to change the date format in your request URL to "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss":/flights/search/id?departure_from=...&arrival_at=...&departure_date=2023-08-27%2012:00:00&return_date=2023-08-28%2012:00:00
`
%20 to represent spaces in the URL.

I recommend using `@PathVariable` instead of `@RequestParam`.

```java
     @GetMapping("/flights/search/{id}/{departureDate}/{returnDate}")
        public ResponseEntity<?> searchFlightsById(
                @RequestParam("departureFrom") Airport departureFrom,
                @RequestParam("arrivalAt") Airport arrivalAt,
                @PathVariable("departureDate") @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") Date departureDate,
                @PathVariable("returnDate") @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") Optional<Date> returnDate) {
        
         
        }
```

the URL might look like this: `/flights/search/1/2023-08-27%2012:00:00/2023-08-28%2012:00:00`

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the issue by declaring the departureDate and arrivalDate as String variables instead of as type Date. Even though the entities had their dates saved as String variables, I was able to conduct necessary operations on them by parsing them with dateFormat as needed. Thanks for all the tips so far!